# JFreeChart - prohibit initial stretching of TimeSeries

Tags: plot, jfreechart, timeserieschart

I would like to adopt sample, well-known demo in JFreeChart showing memory consumption : http://www.koders.com/java/fidAC2CC42CB6511A1240DFE1A6BE1B9D04D34CF001.aspx

Problem:
I don't want it to be initially stretched between both ends of the plot and when the `maximumItemAge` is reached begin to "scroll". 
I want the time range to be of the constant width, and the measurements representation **starting with the left side left blank, filling the plot from the right**.

Scrolling after filling-up the whole plot (`free.setMaximumItemAge(MAXIMUM_AGE);`) is perfectly fine with me.

I've already tried bunch of staff involving `setRange(.., ..)` and `setAutoRange(false)`. 
Seems it's more tricky as the `TimeSeries` are used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the following line: `domain.setFixedAutoRange(MAXIMUM_AGE);`

That will fill your plot from the right and scroll when it's full.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works brilliantly